# After malloc, how to obtain more memory that is still continuous?

Tags: c, malloc

This is an interview question.
If you use malloc to get a piece of memory, such as:

```
char *p = (char *) malloc (100);
```

Now you find you need more memory, say 130. How to obtain the memory such that the new piece of memory is still continuous

Comment: They probably mean you to use `realloc`. The question is a bit vague, though, perhaps because they didn't want it to be too obvious what the answer is. Or perhaps because they aren't very good at asking questions. I could just as well say that `free(p); p = malloc(130);` gives me a new piece of memory, 130 bytes in size, and contiguous (or a null pointer on failure, of course).

Answer (score 9):

```
ptmp = realloc(p, 130);
if (ptmp == NULL)
    handle_out_memory_condition();
p = ptmp;
```

Alternately:

```
p = realloc(p, 130);
if (p == NULL)
    abort();
```

Note that `p` may have a new value, depending on whether the contents needed to be moved to find a contiguous block of the new size.

Documentation: http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/realloc.html

Comment: And if realloc fails you leak the previous 100 bytes `p` pointed to. `realloc` to a temporary variable, test, and if ok assign to the original variable

Comment: `p = realloc(p, 130)` is poor form.  You should always store `realloc`'s result in a temporary value first to make sure that it succeeded.  Otherwise you risk losing the original pointer and leaking memory.

Comment: It might be worth implementing an `xrealloc` wrapper that takes a pointer to pointer as its argument and modifies that only on success, and simply returns success/failure.

Answer (score 0):

Appart from all the obvious `realloc` and `malloc` answers, if your using MSVC, you can use [`_expand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfzt8b7y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which will attempt to resize the block, *without* moving it

Comment: So will realloc(), with a high quality implementation.  In other words, nearly always.

Comment: `realloc` will also attempt to resize the block without moving.  The difference is how they behave if the block cannot be resized without moving.  `_expand` will fail.  `realloc` will move it.

Comment: It's certainly possible that a high quality implementation will allocate blocks of each possible size in their own zone that's exclusively for objects of that particular size, and that in-place resizing will never be possible. Under many workloads, this might be optimal. It could be especially effective with threads since you avoid the lock contention of trying to split/merge free blocks.

Comment: @R: Common sizes?  Yes.  Each possible size?  I hope not! ;-)